# Network request failed on android physical device

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When I am make http call using fetch() it throws me "network request failed". This is happening on Android physical device. (Since, i am using expo so can not make any modification in android or iOS directory)

```
passcodes = async () => { 
    let data = {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      cache: 'no-cache',
      mode: 'same-origin',
      body: JSON.stringify({
          "mobileNumber": this.state.mobileNumber,
          "customerId": "my_customer_id",
          "sessionId": "my_session_id"
      }),
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }
    return await fetch(BaseUrl + 'my_endpoint_url', data)
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((responseJson) => {
         this.setState({
            passCodeText: passCodeData[0],
            passCode: passCodeData[1],
            visibleModal: 1,
            backgroundImage: responseJson.generatePasscodeImage
         });
        })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
       });
  };
```

Comment: Have you tried with a production build, not in dev mode?

Comment: How to do that.?

Comment: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/development-mode/

Comment: Yes. I have tried that, still getting the same issue.

Comment: Moreover, In production mode the application crashed.

Comment: Anyone is having any solution on this. I am trying it from last 2 days and didn't found anything yet. please help.

Comment: Now I am able to replicate this on iOS device also. This is getting very mess for me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.