# Network request failed on physical device(Android and iOS)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When I am make http call using fetch() it throws me "network request failed". This is happening on Android and iOS physical device. (Since, i am using expo so can not make any modification in android or iOS directory)

```
passcodes = async () => { 
    let data = {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      cache: 'no-cache',
      mode: 'same-origin',
      body: JSON.stringify({
          "mobileNumber": this.state.mobileNumber,
          "customerId": "my_customer_id",
          "sessionId": "my_session_id"
      }),
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }
    return await fetch(BaseUrl + 'my_endpoint_url', data)
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((responseJson) => {
         {/* All my business logic goes here..!! */}
        })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
       });
  };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Network request failed on android physical device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57967719/network-request-failed-on-android-physical-device)

Comment: Yes, but didn't any answer yet.